# LINQ - LEFT OUTER JOIN with parameter

Tags: linq, join, parameters

Can someone please help me with an SQL that i just can't get my head around. In T-SQL it looks like this:

```
SELECT  v.errandtype
,   COUNT(s.IVRTaskType)
FROM    V_ERRANDS  v
LEFT OUTER JOIN StatisticsRequest s
    ON  s.IVRTaskType = V.IVRTaskType
    AND s.RegistrationDate >= '2014-03-24 00:00:00.000'
    AND s.RegistrationDate <= '2014-03-24 23:59:59.000'
    AND s.CountryID = 0
GROUP BY v.errandtype
```

but in LINQ...that language is...so freaking weird, i just dont get it.

Greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: See if [this](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Left-Outer-Joins-in-LINQ-with-Entity-Framework) helps with left joins in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

In linq your request will look like this:

```
var statisticsRequest = yourContext.StatisticsRequest.Where(s =>
    s.RegistrationDate >= new DateTime(2014,03,24) &&
    s.RegistrationDate <= new DateTime(2014,03,25) &&
    s.CountryID == 0);

var results =
    from v in yourContext.V_ERRANDS
    group v by v.errandtype into g
    join s in statisticsRequest on s.IVRTaskType = g.FirstOrDefault().IVRTaskType
    select new {
        s.IVRTaskType,
        g.Count()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- `DefaultIfEmpty` for a left join
- `DateTime` variables outside the linq query
- Anonymous type for the grouping, so you can count the other tables column

---

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2014,03,24);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2014,03,25);

var query = from v in context.V_ERRANDS
            from s in context.StatisticsRequest.Where(x => x.IVRTaskType == v.IVRTaskType)
                                               .Where(x => x.RegistrationDate >= start &&  x.RegistrationDate < end)
                                               .Where(x => x.CountryID == 0)
                                               .DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { v, s} by v.errandtype into g
            select new
            {
              errandtype = g.Key,
              count = g.Select(x => x.s.IVRTaskType).Count(),
            };
```